# Looping through a file with two columns and reading those two columns

Tags: shell, for, control-flow

I have a txt files with all the file names I need to analyze. I have this file (inputFile.txt) :

```
/path/file1a  path/file1b 
/path/file2a  path/file2b
```

i have a code which needs two two input files in order to run.

```
./Analyzethis /path/file1a /path/file1b
```

i am trying to create a bash loop to go through my txt files, read through each row and run my code.

I had

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'; for FILE1 in `cat inputFile.txt`; do ./Analyzethis $FILE1; done
```

but, it doesnt work. How can i loop through each row and use the columns with the bash loop?

Comment: A very simple google search for "read file in bash" gives you the answer. eg: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-howto-read-line-by-line-from-file/

Answer (score 5):

This is a bash FAQ: [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

```
while read -r first second; do 
    ./Analyzethis "$first" "$second"
done < inputFile.txt
```

[make sure you quote your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)

While you're reading that FAQ page, make sure you read [Don't try to use "for"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)